# There are no accepted cards available for use with this merchant - Google Pay

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, google-pay

I am trying to integrate Google Pay web into my website but when i click "pay with googlepay" its shows the below error:

**There are no accepted cards available for use with this merchant.**

When i read documentation it says you can add example as merchant for testing, I just wanted to use test environment but still its not working.

Here is the code that i am using:

````
const allowedAuthMethods = ['PAN_ONLY','CRYPTOGRAM_3DS'] ;

const baseCardPaymentMethod = {
  type: 'CARD',
  parameters: {
    allowedCardNetworks: allowedNetworks,
    allowedAuthMethods: allowedAuthMethods 
  }
};

const googlePayBaseConfiguration = {
  apiVersion: 2,
  apiVersionMinor: 0,
  allowedPaymentMethods: [baseCardPaymentMethod]
};

/**
 * Holds the Google Pay client used to call the different methods available
 * through the API.
 * @type {PaymentsClient}
 * @private
 */
let googlePayClient;

/**
 * Defines and handles the main operations related to the integration of
 * Google Pay. This function is executed when the Google Pay library script has
 * finished loading.
 */
function onGooglePayLoaded() {
  googlePayClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({
        environment: 'TEST'
    });

  googlePayClient.isReadyToPay(googlePayBaseConfiguration)
  .then(function(response) {
    if(response.result) {
      createAndAddButton();
    } else {
      alert("Unable to pay using Google Pay");
    }
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.error("Error determining readiness to use Google Pay: ", err);
  });

}

/**
 * Handles the creation of the button to pay with Google Pay.
 * Once created, this button is appended to the DOM, under the element 
 * 'buy-now'.
 */
function createAndAddButton() {

  const googlePayButton = googlePayClient.createButton({

    // currently defaults to black if default or omitted
    buttonColor: 'default',

    // defaults to long if omitted
    buttonType: 'long',

    onClick: onGooglePaymentsButtonClicked
  });

  document.getElementById('buy-now').appendChild(googlePayButton);
}

/**
 * Handles the click of the button to pay with Google Pay. Takes
 * care of defining the payment data request to be used in order to load
 * the payments methods available to the user.
 */
function onGooglePaymentsButtonClicked() {

  const tokenizationSpecification = {
  type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
  parameters: {
    gateway: 'example',
    gatewayMerchantId: 'exampleGatewayMerchantId'
  }
 };

  const cardPaymentMethod = {
  type: 'CARD',
  tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpecification,
  parameters: {
    allowedCardNetworks: ['VISA','MASTERCARD'],
    allowedAuthMethods: ['PAN_ONLY','CRYPTOGRAM_3DS'],
    billingAddressRequired: true,
    billingAddressParameters: {
      format: 'FULL',
      phoneNumberRequired: true
      }
    }
  };

  const transactionInfo = {
  totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
  totalPrice: '123.45',
  currencyCode: 'USD',
  countryCode: 'US'
  };

  const merchantInfo = {
   merchantId: '01234567890123456789', //Only in PRODUCTION
  merchantName: 'Example Merchant Name'
  };

  const paymentDataRequest = Object.assign({}, googlePayBaseConfiguration, {
  allowedPaymentMethods: [cardPaymentMethod],
  transactionInfo: transactionInfo,
  merchantInfo: merchantInfo   
  });

  googlePayClient
  .loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest)
  .then(function(paymentData) {
    processPayment(paymentData);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    // Log error: { statusCode: CANCELED || DEVELOPER_ERROR }
  });
}

function processPayment(paymentData) {
  // TODO: Send a POST request to your processor with the payload
  // https://us-central1-devrel-payments.cloudfunctions.net/google-pay-server 
  // Sorry, this is out-of-scope for this codelab.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // @todo pass payment token to your gateway to process payment
    const paymentToken = paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token;
    console.log('mock send token ' + paymentToken + ' to payment processor');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('mock response from processor');
      alert('done');
      resolve({});
    }, 800);
  });
} ```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are no accepted cards available for use with this merchant.

This message means that the current Google user doesn't have any cards that are compatible with the payment options that the merchant has provided. Specifically `allowedCardNetworks` and `allowedAuthMethods`.

Here is a JSFiddle that I created based on your snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/aumg6ncb/

This is what I get back after clicking on the button:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**If You are using Testing mode:-**
I  think You used testing card on your Chrome browser or Google Wallet

When testing Google Pay you should have a *real* card saved in your Chrome browser or Google Wallet, and have your test API keys/test Google Pay environment active. The real card does not get charged, and Google passes a test card during the checkout flow instead of a real card. Our normal test cards do not work with Google Pay when the user tries to save them in Chrome