# There are no accepted cards available for use with this merchant in Google Payment gateway

Tags: google-pay

There are no accepted cards available for use with this merchant.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNs7I.png)

Comment: I have an error in the google Payment gateway. Does it show There are no Accepted Cards available for use with this merchant. How to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a previous answer I provided for a similar question: [There are no accepted cards available for use with this merchant - Google Pay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58838082/there-are-no-accepted-cards-available-for-use-with-this-merchant-google-pay/58846519#58846519)

It is relates to the intersection of payment methods requested in the API and the cards that the user has available.

If you don't have access to real payment methods to be used with Google Pay, you can use test cards by following the process outlined at https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/resources/test-card-suite or https://github.com/google-pay/google-pay-button/discussions/70.

> The process involves signing in and joining the [googlepay-test-mode-stub-data](https://groups.google.com/g/googlepay-test-mode-stub-data/about) group. Note that this can be your primary Google account or a separate Google account that you use for testing purposes.